# Select query - auto populate empty field

Tags: mysql, select

Is it possible to automatically populate empty or null field with sql query? 
For example i have have table with three columns; ID, Name, Letter.

When fetching data with `SELECT ID, Name, Letter FROM table` i want to fill column Letter with A if it is empty for certain record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
SELECT ID, Name, coalesce(Letter, 'A') as Letter
FROM your_table
```

or [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
SELECT ID, Name, ifnull(Letter, 'A') as Letter
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is it. I didn't even know that is possible and so simple.